# R R6Class global obj in shinyApp

Tags: r, package, shiny, reactive

In my shinyApp, i have one global var : an R6Class, when my app is finished i remove the var from the globalEnv:

```
#' @importFrom shiny reactive
#' @export
gui <- function (port = getOption("shiny.port"),
                 host = getOption("shiny.host", "127.0.0.1"),
                 working.directory = getwd()) {
  appDir <- system.file("shiny", "gui", package = "lidRGUI")
  if (appDir == "") {
    stop("Could not find shiny directory. Try re-installing `lidRGUI`.", call. = FALSE)
  }


  catalogModele <<- CatalogModele$new()
  csvPlotsModel <<- CSVPlotsModel$new()


  on.exit({
    rm(list = c("catalogModele", "csvPlotsModel"), pos = ".GlobalEnv")
    gc()
  })

  shiny::runApp(appDir, display.mode = "normal")
}

#----------------------------------
# Catalog Modele Class
#----------------------------------
#' @importFrom R6 R6Class
#' @importFrom shiny reactiveValues 

#' @export CatalogModele
CatalogModele <- R6Class(
  public = list(
    catalogs = reactiveValues(),
    add_catalog = function(key,value) {
      self$catalogs[[key]] <- value
    },
    get_catalog = function(key) {
      return(self$catalogs[[key]])
    },
    finalize =  function() {
      print("Finalize has been called!")
    }
  )
)
```

The first time i launch gui() catalogModele$catalogs is empty but after the first launch catalogModele$catalogs countains all previous initilizations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is documented in the [R6 vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R6/vignettes/Introduction.html#fields-containing-reference-objects)

> If your R6 class contains any fields that also have reference semantics (e.g., other R6 objects, and environments), those fields should be populated in the initialize method. If the field set to the reference object directly in the class definition, that object will be shared across all instances of the R6 objects.

`reactiveValues` (as well as `reactiveVal`) have reference semantics as mentioned [here](https://shinydata.wordpress.com/2015/02/02/a-few-things-i-learned-about-shiny-and-reactive-programming/#reactivevalues). This is why the solution you posted gives the expected results while the code in your question leads to a "shared catalog" among all instances of the class.

Sorry I didn't think about this when I wrote the answer to [this question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45063205/reactive-field-in-class-shiny-r) but I can correct it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but i don't know why that's works. I replaced :

```
public = list(
    catalogs = reactiveValues(),
```

by

```
public = list(
    catalogs = NULL,
    initialize = function() {
      self$catalogs <- reactiveValues()
    },
```